# Microsoft SideWinder X4 keyboard cutting power and giving errors to kern.log

Tags: 16.04, usb, kernel, xubuntu, keyboard

I got an used Microsoft SideWinder X4 a few weeks ago, and after couple of days using it, the keyboard started cutting power randomly quite often. The previous owner hadn't any issues with it.

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS on a HP Pavilion g6-2252so.

Here's an excerpt from kern.log:

```
Jan  2 22:37:11 milokone kernel: [ 5344.173563] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:37:33 milokone kernel: [ 5366.810694] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:38:35 milokone kernel: [ 5428.757979] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:38:35 milokone kernel: [ 5428.958152] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:39:20 milokone kernel: [ 5473.212059] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:39:31 milokone kernel: [ 5484.152690] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:39:35 milokone kernel: [ 5488.780983] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:41:20 milokone kernel: [ 5593.482215] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:42:18 milokone kernel: [ 5651.060845] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:42:22 milokone kernel: [ 5655.456904] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:42:56 milokone kernel: [ 5689.658948] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:43:46 milokone kernel: [ 5739.953068] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:43:47 milokone kernel: [ 5740.153302] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:46:51 milokone kernel: [ 5924.625932] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:46:51 milokone kernel: [ 5924.825883] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:47:44 milokone kernel: [ 5977.052123] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:49:32 milokone kernel: [ 6085.457408] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:50:23 milokone kernel: [ 6136.507478] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:50:23 milokone kernel: [ 6136.707555] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 22:51:27 milokone kernel: [ 6200.946528] usb 7-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

As you can see, it happens pretty often.

Comment: have you tried any other USB ports? Does this happen with other devices in the same port? Narrow down whether it's the keyboard or the port, it sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: I have tried other USB ports. The keyboard works fine without cutting in and out with Windows and Mac.